# Aborted: core dumped

Tags: c++

I have a structure given below:

```
struct reply_t {
        reply_t (unsigned int _xid){
               xid = _xid;
               cb_present = false;
               buf = NULL;
               sz = 0;
        }
        unsigned int xid;
        bool cb_present; // whether the reply buffer is valid
        char *buf;      // the reply buffer
        int sz;         // the size of reply buffer
};
```

I have a std::map given below:

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::list<reply_t> > reply_window_;
```

Now here is the  problematic the part:

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::list<reply_t> > :: iterator rep_window;
std::list<reply_t> rep_list;
std::list<reply_t> :: iterator rep_it;
rep_window = reply_window_.find(clt_nonce);

if(rep_window!=reply_window_.end()){
         for(rep_it=rep_window->second.begin(); \\
                           rep_it!=rep_window->second.end();rep_it++){
            if((*rep_it).xid<=xid_rep){
                (*rep_it).cb_present = false;
                free((*rep_it).buf);
            }
         }
}
```

In the above code I am just trying to free the memory allocated to ***buf** of the **struct reply_t** pointed by the list iterator. I am not trying to free the memory allocated to the structure **struct reply_t** pointed by the list iterator. But still when I run the code it gives the error below:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could someone please guide me what is going on in here?

Comment: How is buff assigned memory?  Better yet, why are you mixing c-style memory allocations into c++?

Comment: This looks like a much better job for `buf` being a `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` and using `std::remove_if` with `rep_list.erase()` to remove them. Unless, of course, the zombie state is crucial to your design.

Comment: `free()` should only be used to free a pointer that you got from the `malloc` family of functions. The code you have posted doesn't show the allocation of `buf`.

Comment: I know the size of the buf which is "sz". I have used malloc function only to assign memory to buf. Still no luck!!

Comment: Multiple calls to this code will call free on the same pointer. Try setting buf to NULL after you free it to stop this happening.

Comment: Instead of free, use delete [] operator, and also always allocate through new for array allocation (instead of malloc, since your are using C++ struct). Additionally, after delete [], re-assign the pointer to NULL, and before calling delete [] check if not NULL, then only apply delete